# Count checked checkboxes in recyclerView

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes in recyclerView and in that textView is also there.

➡ **I want that when I'll check the checkboxes than  each check boxes should count there own counting and after pressing save button it should save the count in another activity And when I'll again check the checkboxes then it should update that count in another activity. And the count should be individual for each checkboxes in a list.**

**updated `onBindViewHolder`**

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final StudentViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final ListOfNames currentItems = mListOfNames.get(position);
    holder.studentName.setText(currentItems.getStudentName());
    holder.attendence.setText(currentItems.getTempAttendances());
    holder.mCheckedBox.setChecked(currentItems.getTemporaryChecked());

    holder.mCheckedBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int attendances=0 ;
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;
            currentItems.setTempChecked(checkBox.isChecked());
            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                attendances++;
            }
            currentItems.setTempAttendances(attendances);
        }

    });

}
```

**ModelClass**

```
public class ListOfNames {

private String studentName;

private boolean isChecked;
private transient boolean tempChecked;
private transient String  tempAttendances;
private String attandance;


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof ListOfNames) {
        ListOfNames other = (ListOfNames) obj;

        return Objects.equals(this.studentName, other.studentName);
    }
    return super.equals(obj);
}

public ListOfNames(String nStudentName) {
    studentName = nStudentName;

}

public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}



public void setTempChecked(boolean checked) {
    tempChecked = checked;
}

public boolean getTemporaryChecked() {
    return tempChecked;
}

public void checkedToTempChecked() {
    tempChecked = isChecked;
}

public void tempCheckedToChecked() {
    isChecked = tempChecked;
}

public void setTempAttendances(int attendant) {
    tempAttendances = String.valueOf(attendant);
}

public String getTempAttendances() {
    return tempAttendances;
}

public void tempAttendanceToAttendance() {
    attandance = tempAttendances;
}

public void attendanceToTempAttendance() {
    tempAttendances = attandance;
}
```

}

Comment: hi..please share your code

Comment: I have updated my question with codes now u can see @vahab-balouchzahi

Comment: I did some changes in my code ,but  I am not getting actually what i want .You can check once

Comment: The problem lies on your global count variable. So I suggest you remove it and for the count, I suggest to get the attendance value then increment/decrement, and finally, set it back. You mentioned the save button so I suggest creating another temporary transient variable for attendance count. And of course, methods to set and get that temporary variable.

Comment: @ドラゴンハートゼクモル  One doubt as u said    " I  suggest to get the attendance value then increment/decrement", where should i initialized variable so that I'll increment /decrement and, set it back.

Comment: Inside your ListOfNames constructor. By the way, I think even if you don't do it, it's fine. Integers are zero at start even if you don't tell it to.

Comment: I did what u said, but i dint get What i want. I am getting same value of different check boxes and i am to save also that's crct. But how can i update that count also when I'll check it again, i think u r getting this

Comment: I initialized a variable attendance in onBindViewHolder under the Checkbox onCkickListener  and after checking this checkbox I'm incrementing that counting attendance and passing to the temporaryAttendance.. Is it correct that i am doing. I have updated my question with code..  Every time when i started to take attendance of any sub it's started from 1, if I'll consider that past attendance that i took earlier and use it for count again and again then I'll get what I want. But thing is how can use this

Comment: What I meant is you increment/decrement the value inside the item itself. You don't need to declare an outside variable. _Just work with the count variable inside the item._ In fact, you can create an increment and a decrement methods in your ListOfNames class but it will seem ambiguous. So it's your choice.

Comment: Actually it worked just  before a few moment.. I'll show u my code please analyze is it good practice to do like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i want to say thanks for helping me to solve this problem. I tried so much and finally i solved.

**My menu save button**

```
 case R.id.saveButton:

           //codes..

            for (ListOfNames current : listOfNames
            ) {

                current.tempCheckedToChecked();
                current.tempAttendanceToAttendance(); // using transient variable in my model class 
              //this method helps to setting temporary to default value.

            }
            saveData();
            saveAllData();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
```

}

**onBindViewHolder**

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final StudentViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final ListOfNames currentItems = mListOfNames.get(position);

    holder.attendence.setText(currentItems.getTempAttendances());
    holder.mCheckedBox.setChecked(currentItems.getTemporaryChecked());

    holder.mCheckedBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int tempAttendances = currentItems.getTempAttendances();

            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;
            currentItems.setTempChecked(checkBox.isChecked());

            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
               tempAttendances++;
            }
            currentItems.setTempAttendances(tempAttendances);
        }

    });

}
```

**Model Class**

```
public class ListOfNames {

private String studentName;
private boolean isChecked;
private String OverallAttendce;
private transient boolean tempChecked;
private transient int  tempAttendances;
private int attendance;

public ListOfNames(String nStudentName) {
    studentName = nStudentName;
}


          //codes...

public void setTempAttendances(int attendant) {
    tempAttendances = (attendant);
}

public int getTempAttendances() {
    return tempAttendances;
}

public void tempAttendanceToAttendance() {
    attendance = tempAttendances;
}

public void attendanceToTempAttendance() {
    tempAttendances = attendance;
}
```

}

`onBindViewHolder`of Another activity where i am retriving attendances of Student list...

```
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OverallAttendances_Adapter.thisViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ListOfNames currentItems = overallList.get(position);

    //Here I used attendance variable as of `String` type, because in my model class `tempAttendances` is of type `int`. that's why i coverted it into a String.

    String attendance = String.valueOf(currentItems.getTempAttendances());
    holder.stAttendances.setText(attendance);

}
```

And this sloved my problem ..... :)

Comment: Sloved! Sloved!